# std::nullopt_t constructor rationale

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

As stated on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t),

> `std::nullopt_t` must be a [`LiteralType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) and cannot have a default constructor. It must have a `constexpr` constructor that takes some implementation-defined literal type. ... **Notes** `nullopt_t` is not [`DefaultConstructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible) to support both `op = {};` and `op = nullopt;` as the syntax for disengaging an optional object.

...and, a possible implementation is

```
struct nullopt_t {
    constexpr nullopt_t(int) {}
};
```

Actually, after reading this I don't quite understand the rationale behind.

(1) Why make `nullopt_t` not `DefaultConstructible`? I don't quite understand the "...to support both..." part.

(2) Why would a possible constructor take an `int`, while [`boost::none_t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/none_t.hpp) takes an empty type `boost::none_t::init_tag`? How do these two implementations differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why make `nullopt_t` not `DefaultConstructible`?

cppreference needs a small fix there. "not `DefaultConstructible`" is not the right description for the intended semantics.<sup>1</sup>

In any event, the intent is that given `operator=(optional&&)` and `operator=(nullopt_t)`, `opt = {}` will unambiguously go to the first one, instead of causing an ambiguity, and this is done by making it impossible to construct a `nullopt_t` from `{}`. Note the "assign a value" `operator=` is a template, making it nonviable for `= {}` too.

> Why would a possible ctor takes an `int`, while `boost::none_t` takes an empty type `boost::none_t::init_tag`? How do these two implementations differ?

The standard leaves it unspecified how a `nullopt_t` can be constructed. (You are supposed to use `nullopt`.) So typically you just add a constructor taking *something* and ignore it. Exactly what *something* is is up to the implementer.

---

<sup>1</sup> The following pathological implementation meets all the requirements in the current working draft, is not `DefaultConstructible`, but still breaks `opt = {}`:

```
struct nullopt_t {
    constexpr nullopt_t(const nullopt_t&) = default;
};

constexpr nullopt_t nullopt(nullopt_t{});
```

Comment: *So typically you just add a constructor taking something and ignore it. Exactly what something is is up to the implementer.* So is it going to make any difference which type of *something* an implementer use, like in terms of performance/code size/insidious pitfalls/whatever?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Not for any sane implementer.

Comment: @T.C.: "*"not `DefaultConstructible`" is not the right description for the intended semantics.*" It either is or is not DefaultConstructible. From the specification, "Type `nullopt_t` shall not have a default constructor." That makes the behavior pretty clear.

Comment: @NicolBolas What is actually wanted is "not constructible from `{}`". "not `DefaultConstructible`" (with a link to the library `DefaultConstructible` concept) is not sufficient for that. (And the spec is defective as well.)

Comment: @T.C.: Is there a defect report on that? Perhaps an issue filed against the TS? Do you at least have a link to someone saying what the intended semantics are?

Comment: @NicolBolas I just filed an issue (the standard, correctly, doesn't use `DefaultConstructible`, but "shall not have a default constructor" is still insufficient due to aggregates). For the intended semantics, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html#rationale.reset_syntax. It boils down to "make `opt = {}` work".

Comment: @T.C.: From your link, it seems that the defect is that the wording changed *from* "we require that tag `nullopt_t` is not DefaultConstructible". So the cppreference link is what was intended. The definition of `DefaultConstructible` requires (among other things) that `T{}` work. If explicit construction from an empty braced-init-list is not possible for a type, then conversion from an empty braced-init-list is equally impossible. So in what way would doing what the original paper says be non-functional?

Comment: @NicolBolas To be `DefaultConstructible`, you have to meet *all* the requirements, but to be not `DefaultConstructible`, you only have to break *one* of them (e.g., that `T()` work).

Comment: Wouldn't an `explicit` default constructor work as well (i.e. avoid ambiguity)? An `explicit` default constructor  seems to be used quite a lot for such "tag"/"token" types: `std::allocator_arg_t`, `std::in_place_t`, `std::in_place_type_t`, `std::in_place_index_t`, `std::nothrow_t`, etc.

Comment: @Matthias I was much confused by this too. Tests show that both GCC and MSVC (but not Clang) consider that the explicitness of the constructor does not resolve the ambiguity: https://godbolt.org/z/4GPsrYW13. And it seems Clang is wrong, as cppreference.com mentions this for copy-list-initialization: "both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, but only non-explicit constructors may be called". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization